# Split a node element by a delimiter but retaining all the other nodes

Tags: xml, split, xslt-2.0

I am struggling with a split in XSLT 2.0.
I have a paragraph that I need that some portion of the node goes into a different tag and the other portion of the node into another tag.
I used string function but that does not copy the nodes, just the text (string).
I am trying to split the **para** based on the " : " delimiter, but to no avail...

my Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <para id="pa3" class="para_index">
  <alinea>Achard de Saint-Victor : <marquage typemarq="italique"><liensimple id="l3"    xlink:href="xxx://numero:isbn:xxxx/article:page:397">397</liensimple></marquage></alinea>
 </para>
</root>
```

my Desired Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <para id="pa3">
     <listerelation type="1">
      <lrsource>
       <alinea>Achard de Saint-Victor</alinea>
      </lrsource>
      <lrcible>
       <alinea><marquage typemarq="italique"><liensimple id="l3" xlink:href="xxx://numero:isbn:xxxx/article:page:397">397</liensimple></marquage>
  </alinea>
      </lrcible>
     </listerelation>
    </para>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general solution for that type of problem is usually done in two steps where the first step splits text nodes on the delimiter sequence (e.g. `:`) converting it into an empty element (e.g. `<colon/>`) and then a second step that uses `for-each-group select=".//node()" group-ending-with="colon"` to split and reconstruct the partial subtrees; here is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="colon-char-to-element" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:mode name="split" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="para[contains(., ' : ')]">
    <xsl:variable name="para-with-colon-el" as="element(para)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" mode="colon-char-to-element"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @class"/>
      <listrelation type="1">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$para-with-colon-el//node()" group-ending-with="colon">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
              <lrsource>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-with-colon-el" mode="split"/>
              </lrsource>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <lrcible>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-with-colon-el" mode="split"/>
              </lrcible>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </listrelation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="colon-char-to-element" match="text()[contains(., ' : ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' : ')"/>
    <colon/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' : ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#current"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() intersect current-group()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="colon"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is e.g.

```
<root xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <para id="pa3">
      <listrelation type="1">
         <lrsource>
            <alinea>Achard de Saint-Victor</alinea>
         </lrsource>
         <lrcible>
            <alinea>
               <marquage typemarq="italique">
                  <liensimple id="l3" xlink:href="xxx://numero:isbn:xxxx/article:page:397">397</liensimple>
               </marquage>
            </alinea>
         </lrcible>
      </listrelation>
   </para>
</root>
```

If you are stuck with an XSLT 2.0 processor (most people for XSLT 2 tend to use Saxon or Altova who both for years support XSLT 3) you can't use the `xsl:mode` declarations I have used but should be able to set up e.g. a generic template declaring the identity transformation for all modes e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:template mode="#all" match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#current"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="para[contains(., ' : ')]">
    <xsl:variable name="para-with-colon-el" as="element(para)">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" mode="colon-char-to-element"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @class"/>
      <listrelation type="1">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$para-with-colon-el//node()" group-ending-with="colon">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="position() mod 2 = 1">
              <lrsource>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-with-colon-el" mode="split"/>
              </lrsource>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <lrcible>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-with-colon-el" mode="split"/>
              </lrcible>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
      </listrelation>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="colon-char-to-element" match="text()[contains(., ' : ')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ' : ')"/>
    <colon/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., ' : ')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="node()">
    <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::node() intersect current-group()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="#current"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() intersect current-group()" mode="#current"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template mode="split" match="colon"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response, I will give it a try on my end and come back with a feedback! But analyzing visually the code I think I understand what you propose. In order for a split to happen on nodes, the delimiter should be an element and not a text node and after that it's a matter of grouping the nodes based on the delimiter element. Thank you again!

Comment: Everything worked like a charm. Thanks again for your help!